# Adding attachment creates new MailItem in Outlook Inbox folder

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am working with an empty msg file created via Outlook once. The following code adds a attachment to an email (you can save it using `msg.SaveAs(Path=save_path)`).

```
import win32com.client

msg_path = r'C:\email.msg'
attachment_path = r'C:\specimen.pdf'

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(msg_path)

msg.Attachments.Add(Source=attachment_path)
```

Problem: the last line `msg.Attachments.Add(Source=attachment_path)` creates a new duplicate mail in inbox folder.

I found an old discussion of the problem here:
[Adding attachment creates new MailItem in inbox folder](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/bed6509c-00ee-4bf4-9ed9-4a91b7dc47df/adding-attachment-creates-new-mailitem-in-inbox-folder?forum=outlookdev).
Here are some citations from there:

> `OpenSharedItem` always creates a temporary message and imports the
>   contents of the MSG file; it does not work directly with the specified
>   file.
>
> The problem is that the message gets *saved* when you add an
>   attachment, but there is nothing you can do about that.
>
> The important part is that OOM is *not* working with an MSG file -
>   once it is imported into a message in one of Outlook folders, the
>   original MSG file is out of the picture.

Are there any workarounds to prevent Outlook from creating a new message in Inbox folder? If not, how to make Outlook save it in Junk Email folder?

My goal is to modify the existing empty msg file: add a subject line and an attachment.

Comment: It turned out that even manual attachment in the msg file (Insert -> Attach file) creates a new mail in Inbox folder.

Comment: Manually composing a new email, attaching a file to it, and then saving as msg stand-alone file does not create a new email in Inbox folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question,

The idea is to create a new mail instead of modifying the existing one.
Here is the code:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
msg = outlook.CreateItem(0)
msg.Attachments.Add(Source=str(attachment_path))
msg.SaveAs(Path=save_path)
```

Comment: But your code would not import any data from the existing MSG file.

Comment: Correct, and it should not because I was working with an empty MSG file: nothing to import.